# How do I make a function that does NOT run when a specific event is fired

Tags: c#, .net, events, unity-game-engine

**Edit:** For clarification, this is in Unity, and is tied to Update(). So the events will be triggered once per frame for any number of frames. Both events can be triggered independently by the user, but there is an overlap in which both can be triggered. In this case I only want one of the two methods that will be called by the two events to actually run.

I'm trying to make a method that is called by one event and other method that is called by a 2nd event be linked in a way that only one of those two methods can be called or ran at the same time.

The events are triggered by an action of the user, both events can be triggered at the same time. But I only want one of the two methods that would be called to actually run if both events are triggered.

I was thinking something along the like of the following example, obviously the example may not be accurate, but the gist of what I am trying to accomplish is there.

Pseudo Code Example:

```
public delegate void OneHandler();
public event OneHandler OneEvent;
private void One()
{
    if(some requirement && TEvent != null)
    {
        TEvent();
    }
}

public delegate void TwoHandler();
public event TwoHandler TwoEvent;
private void Two()
{
    if(some requirement && TEvent != null)
    {
        TEvent();
    }
}
```

---

```
SomeClass.OneEvent += ActionOne();
SomeClass.TwoEvent += ActionTwo();


private void ActionOne()
{
    if(TwoEvent is not firing)
    {
        Do Something;
    }
}

private void ActionTwo()
{
    if(OneEvent is not firing)
    {
        Do Something;
    }
}
```

---

A crude diagram. The tan area moves down/left, the green areas move diagonally. I essentially want the tan area which have their own events, to not run their methods if the mouse is within that entire area.

[image]

Comment: If the events come from the same thread, they will never be invoked at the same time. I am not sure if it is your case or not.

Comment: As I understand it, you want to ensure that you don't execute two particular events for the same frame. Reset an interlocked flag in the [Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventFunctions.html) function which occurs once per frame. ([Event execution order.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)) Then attempt an interlocked test and set in the events. Only the first will succeed for any given frame. If an event fails to acquire the flag it should simply exit.

Answer (score 2):

Events fire one at a time, not all at once. Even if the same user action was going to cause both events to fire one after the other, there is no way to know that both events will fire, or in what order they will fire.

---

To be more clear: I didn't mean events can never be fired concurrently. I mean that, in general, there is no piece of code that determines, for a particular situation, the complete set of events which will be fired. You can't tell ahead of time which will fire, or in which order, or even on which threads.

For example, a particular user interface action (or user gesture) might cause several events to fire. In general, you can't depend on the number of events to be fired, or the order in which they will be fired.

There are some situations, like in ASP.NET web forms, where you can be assured that if the user clicks a button which has a `Click` event handler, that the page `Load` event will fire and then that the button `Click` event will fire. But this is because this behavior is defined and documented that way. If the order changed, or if, for instance, the page `Load` event stopped firing, then this would break a large number of ASP.NET web forms applications.

Comment: Although I'm willing to bet the questioner is targeting a UI (in which case you're guaranteed to be single-threaded), not all cases where an event can be fired necessarily are UI-driven. A class consumed in a multithreaded environment (say, a multi-core box running a message handling server) could theoretically execute two events concurrently.

Comment: I will clarify. I didn't mean they could never be fired concurrently. I mean that, in general, there is no piece of code that determines, for a particular situation, the complete set of events which will be fired. You can't tell ahead of time which will fire, or in which order, or even on which threads.

Comment: This is in Unity, I am triggering an event by a mouse pointer location. If the mouse is in a certain location both events will be triggered on Update() once per frame. I need one of the two methods that are triggered to have "priority" in a way that if both events trigger (and both methods are called) only one of the methods will actually run.

Comment: Unless Unity defines the order of the events or defines that both events will fire, then you're out of luck. This is a fairly basic part of event-driven programming. It's a lot like developing device drivers for an interrupt-driven architecture. Don't depend on the order.

Comment: True enough, but that's not really what he was asking; he just wants to guarantee that only one of the handlers will execute if they both get triggered simultaneously. (Which, to be fair, is an odd requirement: are there really expected instances where both events would be fired at the exact same time? What about the case when one fires two milliseconds after the first, which may be just enough time for the first handler to exit?)

Comment: The events can both be triggered on the same frame. It is tied to mouse position, for the sake of example imagine an Venn Chart. One side is an area that triggers event 1, the other side triggers event 2, the overlapping middle triggers event 1 and 2 as long as the mouse remains there. I am trying to ensure that when both events are triggered, only one of the methods actually run. There is an overlapping area where I only want one of the methods to actually run. I could exclude that area from one of the events, though I believe that would be every complicated in comparison.

Comment: My point is that, in general, there is no concept of "the set of handlers which will execute due to a given trigger". I can conceive of a subsystem which might define such a concept. It could then allow the developer to intervene and customize which handlers will get executed. But I have never seen such a subsystem.

Comment: What is your reason to only want one to run? Maybe if one runs then there's no need for the other to run, so the other is redundant? Or would something bad happen if they both ran for the same frame?

Comment: Also, does Unity perhaps define that all the events for one frame will execute before the next frame?

Comment: My understanding is not as deep as yours, but as far as I know all events in one frame are executed before the next frame. I have the mouse move the camera based on the mouse position, up down left right..etc I want to add a diagonal movement that does not rely on the user getting the mouse in the correct area where lets say right/up overlap. Instead of using the 90 degree angle of a corner where they overlap, I am using a triangular area of the corner to move diagonally. If the user pushes the mouse too far in triggers both, which causes the screen to move at 2x the speed.

Comment: It also causes them to accidentally trigger moving up or right while trying to move diagonally up/right in that triangular area of the corner. (ran out of characters)

Comment: Made a crude diagram, was unable to edit my comment to add it. My apologies for cluttering the place up. http://i.imgur.com/R10KYtg.png
The tan area moves down/left, the green areas move diagonally. I essentially want the tan area which have their own events, to not run their methods if the mouse is within that entire area.

Comment: I added your diagram to your question. Not knowing Unity, I wonder why not have a single event handler and call various methods based on the mouse position. If you can tell which area the mouse is in, you can decide which method to call.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is guarantee that concurrent triggering (like two threads running on different cores) will never be allowed, you'll want to use something like a mutex. You would have both handlers perform a WaitOne(0) to see if the other handler is working, returning immediately if the call returns false (since the other method must be executing) then in a guaranteed-execution block (such as a finally) you would release the mutex.

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for the reply. Let me clarify. 

This is in Unity, and both events are tied to Update(), and will trigger once per frame. Both events can be triggered at the same time by the user, and both methods are called at the same time (by same time, I mean both in one frame).

 I am trying to figure out a non-messy way to prevent both methods from running. So if Event 1 and Event 2 where triggerd on the same frame only the method event 2 will call actually runs. 

This is also tied to mouse position, so the events will fire every frame for however long the mouse is in that position.

Comment: Ok, so this is less about "at the same time" and more about "within the same execution context." In that case, I would change my answer to have a manual reset event that is reset on every frame; you'd still do the WaitOne in the handler, you just wouldn't need to release anything (the render loop would handle that).

Answer (score 0):

How about use bool variable as flag ?

```
private bool flag[2] = [false, false];

private void ActionOne()
{
    flag[0] = true;        
    if(!(flag[0])&&flag[1]))
    {
        Do Something;
    }
    flag[0] = false;
}

private void ActionTwo()
{
    flag[1] = true;
    if(!(flag[0] && flag[1]))
    {
        Do Something;
    }
    flag[1] = false;
}
```

Comment: I see a threading issue, here: what if you perform the check and then your thread is suspended immediately afterwards, after which the other handler performs *its* check?

Comment: Yeah - you need to interlock access to the flags.